# Your experiences with Visual Studio 2010 CTP?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I just saw the anouncement for the [Visual Studio CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=922B4655-93D0-4476-BDA4-94CF5F8D4814&displaylang=en) today, and am currently waiting for all those files to download...

Have you already tried the CTP, or maybe a previous version? What are your thoughts? There is another question [What features would you most like to see in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206943/what-features-would-you-most-like-to-see-in-visual-studio-2010), now here it is, what do you think?

Answer (score 4):

Downloaded, running, looking at the walk throughs, here are some of the things I've seen so far.

- Customisable Start page in XAML (don't know if I'd bother)
- Zoomable code editor (I bet this was a feature request from MS evangelists)
- Highlight current line in editor (YES! the SlickEdit addin slowed my machine horribly. However, I haven't yet managed to get it to work in the CTP)
- Stuff for hooking into editor and adding your own formatting, highlighting, intellisense, smart tags etc. (Don't think I'll be needing that any time soon)
- Call Hierarchy - tree view of who calls your method and who your method calls
- Static type 'dynamic' - strictly speaking this is C#4.0, not VS2010 (watch the [PDC Future of C#](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL16/) talk by Anders to get some of that Wow factor)
- Generate from usage: This is so cool, you write your test, then use VS refactoring to create all of the boilerplate class/property/method definitions for your code. (And you can generate an entire class from an anonymous class!)
- Quick search - (equivalent of Code Rush Ctrl Shift Q)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't but [ayende](http://ayende.com/) posted about this [yesterday](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/10/27/visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded it, but didn't have enough space to unpack it :-)

But I've heard rumors [that VS2010 gets a WCF interface](http://www.heise-online.co.uk/news/PDC-Visual-Studio-2010-gets-a-new-WPF-interface--/111833). That would be awesome, but it would also antiquate the 7 GIGs I just downloaded a couple of days ago :-)

Comment: Yeah. There was a presentation about this at the PDC. Really cool.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the most amazing stuff in VS2010 is a [historical debugger](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/VisualStudio/Historical-Debugger-and-Test-Impact-Analysis-in-Visual-Studio-Team-System-2010/). I've been dreaming about such tool since MSVS2003. Integrated code analysis is a very nice feature too.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with it for a while; some thoughts:

- (ide) the new WPF interface, while shiny, plays merry heck with remote desktop to my VM... I'm hoping that will be optimized (or an option etc) before RTM
- (language/framework) liking the new `dynamic` support; shame it isn't complete (it doesn't provide operator support, which .NET 4.0 is meant to deliver)
- (framework) interesting [new `Expression` support](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/search/label/expression) - shame the language doesn't offer it directly, but very powerful for `Expression` fans

I haven't had time to play with the COM stuff (no-PIA/no-ref), but looks useful.